# ffmpeg -ss flag does not work

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to split an audio file as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -vn -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:03:21 01-track1.mp3
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -vn -acodec copy -ss 00:03:21 -t 00:08:26 02-track2.mp3
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -vn -acodec copy -ss 00:08:26 -t 00:10:45 03-track3.mp3
```

That seems to work but I noticed that the starttime is not correct. So now I have files like this:

```
track1.mp3: 00:03:21
track2.mp3: 00:08:25
track3.mp3: 00:10:44
```

The endtime is correct but it always start from the beginning of the audio file instead of the place it should start

Comment: In case it helps ... From my old notes: **1:** `-ss` is the start point in `hh:mm:ss` from the **beginning** of the video file. **2:** 
`-t` is the length of time in `hh:mm:ss` of the segment. In other words, a thirty second segment is being processed. `-t` is not needed if the segment extends to the end of the video.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comment of @DK Bose, I got it working:

Instead of using `ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -vn -acodec copy -ss 00:03:21 -t 00:08:26 02-track2.mp3`

I needed to say what the duration of the file must be. So from 00:03:21 to 00:08:26 is 00:05:05 minutes and the command should look like `ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -vn -acodec copy -ss 00:03:21 -t 00:05:05 02-track2.mp3`

Then I get an audio file with the duration of 05:05 minutes.

Another possibility (with recent ffmpeg versions) is using the -to parameter like this: `ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -vn -acodec copy -ss 00:03:21 -to 00:08:26 02-track2.mp3`